# Redirect specific url to static page using lighttpd

Tags: redirect, https, url-rewriting, lighttpd, vhosts

I need use lighttpd like a file server for specifics URL. For example:

http://www.test1/file1 for download (over http) file F1
http://test2/aaa?bbb for download file F2

http://test3:8080 for file F3
https:/test4/ccc/ddd for file F4
...

Note use of differents ports and protocols http and https

I used redirect but doesn't work for me :(

I used lighttpd in Linux server and Firefox browser for testing. I expect that when I put in Firefox:

http://www.test1/file1

The browser download F1 file

And they same with another URL...

I appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Your question is worded extremely poorly and lacking basic required information, such as the configuration that you tried.

Comment: Sorry, here my config file (only relevant part): SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {

  $HTTP["host"] == "test1" {
    url.redirect = ("" => "https://test2/static_page"),
    url.redirect-code = 302
  }
}

Comment: You do not know what you're doing and you are using substitution variables without explaining what they mean to you (because they mean very little to me).  Is test2 a domain?  Is it `www.test2` or `test2`?  `url.redirect = ("" => "http://www.test2/static_page")`  The language barrier is one hurdle.  A much larger hurdle is your way-too-brief explanation what you're trying to do.